# which Build tool is used in grails?

Tags: grails, gradle, ant

which Build tool is used in grails?How a project war is created in grails,is it ANT or GRADLE build tool and how it is created using these build tools

Answer (score 0):

Please read the document.You will find your answer.
http://grails.io/post/138665751278/grails-3-gradle-multi-project-builds .

You can build war simply "grails war " command .and for production "grails prod war"

Comment: can i get some more details about Gradle build tool,please note am a beginner to grails

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses GRADLE build tool.
You need to specify the war name in the war command.

```
grails war project.war
```